# Most efficient structure to use as an agenda with contacts in C

Tags: c

I have to do an exercise in which I have to create an agenda. I have to do commands such as search, add, eliminate, etc. I have 2 approaches in mind that but I´m no sure which one to choose. I was thinking general binary tree since I would use the name of the contact  for comparison, and have the tree in alfabetical order. However, I also thought about using an ordenered general list. Which one should I choose and why?
Thank you!

Comment: Human agenda's are so short/small, that frankly, practically any data structure will be fine. A linear scan through thousands of events to add/find/delete one will be basically instant.

Comment: How many are you going to store? Thousands? 100 milions? What operations are most important, or how is efficiency going to be measured? Searching? Adding? Deletion?

Comment: I'd use a sqlite database.